# Detect/find *.pdf on server (with php?) and pass it to .js file

Tags: javascript, php

I'm completely new to javascript. I have a .js (running on webserver) file with two options:

```
defaultUrl: {
    value: "filename.pdf",
    kind: OptionKind.VIEWER
  },
```

and instead of filaname.pdf name I would like it to detect any .pdf file in current working folder (there will always be one, but each time with different filename) and return it's name here

The file is on shared web hosting - so I probably can run some .php code to find the filename

edit:

```
// If absolute URL from the remote server is provided, configure the CORS
// header on that server.
var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ba2edeae/examples/learning/helloworld.pdf';

// Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

// The workerSrc property shall be specified.
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

// Asynchronous download of PDF
var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);
loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
  console.log('PDF loaded');
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to replace the filename when loading the page or after the page is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have this directory structure:

```
$ tree test
test
├── test-find-pdf.php
└── test.pdf

0 directories, 2 files
```

Then you can get all pdf files in the current working directory using `glob()`. To return the name of the first pdf file found modify your php script like this:

```
<?php
    # file test-find-pdf.php

    $allPdfFiles = glob("*.pdf");
    echo $allPdfFiles[0];
?>
```

That way you can call it from your javascript with an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) (aka Ajax request) like this:

```
<script>
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET","test-find-pdf.php");
request.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
   if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) {
      console.log(request.responseText);
   } else {
      console.warn(request.statusText, request.responseText);
   }
});
request.send();
</script>
```

So on load of your html document the Ajax returns the result of the php file and prints it to the console <kbd>F12</kbd> in your browser. From there you have to find a way to assign it to your json object.

Make sure that the path to your php file in `request.open()` is correct.

Further information on `glob()` can be found [in the php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).

Comment: Ok I got the php running and it shows the array, but I'm having trouble inserting it into default url value.

should it be like :
```
defaultUrl: {
    value: $allPdfFiles[0],
    kind: OptionKind.VIEWER
  },
```

Comment: I've just edited my answer to include a simple example of a vanilla XMLHttpRequest to get the result of the php file in javascript. It could also be done using a library like e.g. jQuery.

Comment: Thanks again, I got the php running and the $allPdfFiles[0] is correct, but still have trouble assigning it in .js file :/

Comment: could you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68707517/edit) to include your javascript snippet?

Comment: It's part of pdf.js viewer file (viewer.js)

Comment: Solved it by making server parse .js files for php - and putting php code into .js file. Still thanks your answer helped!